# Should I be using controllers.py or @staticmethod in Django?

Tags: python, django

The person on our team who initially taught us django (and has subsequently left) utilized a controllers.py file for helper functions. A lot of these functions are directly related to classes. I prefer to use @staticmethod to house these helpers with the classes they're related to. For example, rather than doing this:

```
# controllers.py
def process_entry():
    # do some exciting stuff that might not have to do with an instance
```

Called like this:

```
from myapp.controllers import process_entry
process_entry()
```

I'd prefer this:

```
# models.py
class Entry(models.Model):
    name = CharField...
    # some other fields

    @staticmethod
    def process_entry():
    # do some exciting stuff that might not have to do with an instance
```

Called like so:

```
from myapp.models import Entry
Entry.process_entry()
```

Is there a preferred, standard way to deal with situations like this or is it just personal preference? Does anyone else utilize a controllers.py file? What goes in there?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Possibly a better example, commissions.

```
# models.py
class Commission(models.Model):
    check = ForeignKey
    payment = ForeignKey
    # other fields

class Check(models.Model):
    # fields

class Payment(models.Model):
    # fields
```

Any time a Check or Payment instance is modified an adjustment as to be made to any related Commission instances or any time someone wants to manually run commissions, they can do so. So where should run_commissions() go? I prefer this, but apparently this shouldn't be encapsulated in a data-related model?

```
# models.py
class Commission(models.Model):
    check = ForeignKey
    payment = ForeignKey
    # other fields

   @staticmethod 
   def run_commissions():
       # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are used for grouping related functions in one class (mostly for factory methods), beside that, there is no difference between static method and function.

BUT. In your example you are assigning behavior to DATABASE model. DATABASE models are not LOGIC models, and you should separate them from your app logic. Anyway, *controllers* is also a bad name in that matter.

I'm not sure what *process_entry* does, but if it's only changing one Entry entity, then it can be named: Entry.process(), but NOT Entry as DB model! just another Entry class. However if that function does more than just changing Entry, then it shouldn't be assigned to Entry entity, but made as a service function.